# Search form breaks up in responsive Twitter Bootstrap site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to create a responsive site. I'm loving the frame work and everything works fine, except for the search form that I have in the header. Its kind of large and expands over 7 grids, and when I make the window smaller than ca 512 px the submit button suddenly slips down under the input area, which is not very neat. I'm using the "form-horizontal" class, which the documentation suggests I should use.

Here's the code for the form section. Any help much appreciated!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span7">



<form class="form-horizontal" id="searchfield" action="search.php" method="get">

 <input  name="address" placeholder="Write something..." type="text" class="span7 search-query field">
 <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Search</button>

</form>


</div>


<div class="span4">
<a href="form1.php"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse span4">Skapa    boende</button></a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but should you not be using the row-fluid class instead of just row? Also you're telling the search field it should be span7 wide the same as it's parent but you also have an input in there too so how can they both fit in a span7?

Comment: Buttons, in bootstrap, should have `btn btn-primary`, not `btn-primary`

Answer (score 0):

What bootstrap responsive does is it makes the site 'responsive' to the user's [viewport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport). That means that if the viewport's width jumps below a given point, the layout changes. The responsive sheet defines that `.span1-12` will not float anymore, below that certain point. Thus placing one below the other.

If you don't want this to happen, you have to: a. Remove the responsive sheet, or b. do some crazy ugly workarounds. The last one, is the one that you shouldn't be doing. Though, it would probably work, the chances of it breaking features, is very big.

Though, there might be something that's worth mentioning. There has been a guy (Arnold Daniels) that has created some neat extentions for bootstrap, including something he called a ['desktop row'](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#row-desktop). It's just a row, but the responsive changes start at a tablet-viewport. This is not what you want, but it shows you can change the responsive-sheet.